# double prefered over float at constructortion

Tags: java, c++, constructor, double

Please explain:

I'm declaring a class with 2 constructors as following:

```
class A {
public :
  A (double x) {cout << "DOUBLE \n";}
  A (float x) {cout << "FLOAT \n";}
};
```

Then:

```
A a (3.7);
```

This result with *DOUBLE* as output.
I've tried this also on java - same result.
Can anyone explain why?

EDIT: I do realise double is the default type for number such as *3.7* My question is why and if there is a good reason for that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "default". The compiler needs a way to differentiate between different types of litterals. Single quotes denote characters, double quotes denote string litterals, digits with no decimal point denote integers. Digits with a decimal point denote doubles and finally digits with decimal points ending with f denote a float.

Comment: Do you have an argument as to why it should be a float? It seems a tad pointless without. *Something* has to be the default if you don't want to annoy everyone by making them put a suffix on everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `3.7` literal is a `double`. If you want `float`, use `3.7f`. In C++, it is specified in the standard, **2.14.4 Floating Literals**. The most relevant section is

> The type of a floating literal is `double` unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes `f` and `F` specify
>   `float`, the suffixes `l` and `L` specify long double.

This doesn't answer *why* this is so. I imagine it is because the way it was in C, and the reason it is that way in C must be, to some level, arbitrary.

Comment: Why the standart is a double rather than a float?

Comment: @RanEldan I don't know the history of this convention.

Comment: That's basically my question

Comment: @RanEldan Then you should edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Wild guess for rationale behind C's default-double: default-double may lead to less loss of precision when converting from base-10 literal to base-2 floating-point.

Comment: @moshbear: Having the default be `float` would be very dangerous in a language which allows implicit float-to-double conversions.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to have been at least a couple of reasons for this.

First of all, the PDP-11 floating point unit had a single precision mode and a double precision mode. Switching between modes was possible, but fairly slow. At the same time, execution in double precision mode was almost as fast as in single precision mode (if memory serves, even faster in a few cases).

Second, early C didn't have a way to specify function parameter types. The standard library functions only accepted double precision floating point (since it gave extra precision almost for free). Writing the library to deal with both single and double precision floating point would have (approximately) doubled the effort, but provided little real advantage.

Answer (score 0):

By default 3.7 will be considered as `double` in java. If you want it treated as `float`, you need to append f, 3.7f.

Please refer [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

Comment: Why the default is a double rather than a float?

Comment: @RanEldan: Updated answer with Java Language specification reference.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point doesn't have an exact representation.  This means that 3.7d != 3.7f as these have different precision. As 3.7d has more precision it makes a better choice for the default value 3.7.  If you used 3.7f you can assign this to a `double` and be unaware that this lack the precision of a double e.g.

```
double d = 3.7f;
System.out.println(d); // doesn't print 3.7 as expected!
```